# Access denied for user '' @'localhost' to database '' SQL=CREATE DATABASE `` CHARACTER SET `utf8mb4`

Tags: html, string

i was restoring a website backup with akeeba with kickstart and i got this error message "Access denied for user '' @'localhost' to database '' SQL=CREATE DATABASE `` CHARACTER SET `utf8mb4`

i tried logging in to database via Enter phypmyadmin to see if how to solve this issue but couldnt, since
i am a novice when it comes to database.

pls help me solve this problem

i logged in to phpmyadmin to see if user was created and yes it is yet i dont know why access was denied

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.